# Clarification on HW Question: Show $inf_{n}P(A_{n})>0$ implies $P(A_{n}\text{i.o.})>0$.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

So this was a problem on one of my assignments this week in an introductory probability course, and am a bit confused because I think I am mis-interpreting what the notation means and what the point of the question is.  Other people in the class felt similarly.

Let $A_{1},A_{2},\ldots$ be events in a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ such that $\inf_{n}P(A_{n})>0$.  Show that $P(A_{n}\;\text{i.o.})>0.$

So as I understand it, i.o. means infinitely often (akin to a $\limsup$).  I'm not sure how I'm supposed to read the i.o. when it's in the argument of the probability measure.  I am thinking of it as $P(A_{n})>0$ i.o., which seems trivial if $\inf_{n}P(A_{n})>0$.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on with this question?  I wanted to ask here first before I take it to the professor for clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: "I wanted to ask here first before I take it to the professor for clarification". Why is that so? The other order might seem natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"$A_n \text{ i.o.}$" does mean "infinitely often".  It's shorthand for the event
$$A := \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m}^\infty A_n$$
which is sometimes also denoted $\limsup A_n$.  The reason for the name is that $\omega \in A$, iff $\omega \in A_n$ for infinitely many $n$.

So you are being asked to show
$$P \left( \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n=m}^\infty A_n \right) > 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this is a statement on Borel–Cantelli lemma (I'm not an expert in probability). This link might help you with the notation for sure and also a little bit on the proof. http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/stochastic-I/stochastic-I-BC.pdf.

Sorry for not being able to help more than that.